# Python classmethods: what's the difference between a member of an instance and a member of the class?

Tags: python, static-methods

In python, `staticmethod`s are "just functions", and I can refer to them in two different ways:

```
>>> class A:
...     @staticmethod
...     def f():
...         pass
... 
>>> a=A()
>>> A.f
<function A.f at 0x7f20f8cd3f28>
>>> a.f
<function A.f at 0x7f20f8cd3f28>
>>> a.f is A.f
True
```

Both `a.f` and `A.f` are names that refer to the same object, which happens to be "just a function". Great.

Now, say I have a `classmethod`:

```
>>> class B:
...     @classmethod
...     def f(cls):
...         pass
... 
>>> b=B()
>>> b.f is B.f
False
```

I know that `b.f` and `B.f` are *not* functions: they're *bound mothods*. This means that the `cls` argument is implicit, and is always equal to `B`. Because of this, I would understand that if `B2` is a subclass of `B`, `B2().f is B().f` would be false, because they're bound methods with different `cls` arguments. But I don't understand why `B().f is B.f` yields `False`. Shouldn't they be the same object, just like `A().f` and `A.f`?

EDIT: This question is not the same as "[What is the difference between @staticmethod and @classmethod in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python)". I know the difference between `staticmethod` and `classmethod`. I want to know one specific thing, which is not addressed in the "umbrella" question linked.

Comment: A class is like a definition.  The `instance` is an actual use of that definition.  So the `class` is a recipe, and the `instance` is the cake.  Since the recipe is not the cake, and only the instructions on how to make a cake, they are not the same.

Comment: @DuckPuncher did you read the body of my question? I want to know why `B().f is B.f` is false and `A().f is A.f` is true.

Comment: See also, "User-defined methods" here: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`B().f` and `B.f` are different objects because Python creates a new bound method object each time you refer to a non-static method via attribute access.

For example, `B.f is B.f` is also `False`.

```
>>> B.f is B.f
False
```

Similarly, you will get a new method object even if the instance stays the same:

```
>>> b = B()
>>> b.f is b.f
False
```

`@staticmethod` creates a new static method object, but

> When a static method object is retrieved from a class or a class
>   instance, the object actually returned is the wrapped object, which is
>   not subject to any further transformation.

(from [Data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy))

In this case `A.f` always returns the same `f` function object.

Comment: FWIW, `b=B(); b.f is b.f` is false, also.